# Basic Explanation of Actors in Erlang

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, erlang, actor

I am trying to put together a very basic explanation of actors in Erlang. It is supposed to be as bare-bones as possible, but without leaving out key features of the theory or the Erlang implementation of it. This is my explanation:

> The actor model is a mathematical model of concurrent computation that treats *actors* as the universal primitives of concurrent computation. The actor is a *computational entity* that, in response to a message it receives, can concurrently (1) send a finite number of messages to other actors, (2)  create a finite number of new actors, and (3) designate the behavior to be used for the next message it receives.
>
> In Erlang, each actor is a separate process in the virtual machine, implemented by a function. Processes communicate by sending messages to each other. Every message is explicit, traceable and safe. The messages are received in a mailbox and stored in the order in which they are received. They are stored there until the receiving process takes them out to be read. This is called asynchronous message passing.
>
> [image: Blockquote]

What do you guys think? Is it OK? Should I add or change anything? Thanks.

Comment: @ElToro1966 guess you could add a mailbox to the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would help yourself if you didn't confuse actors with Erlang processes. You started with Wikipedia's description of Actor model only to seamlessly start writing about Erlang processes, like if it was one and the same. Actor model is a mathematical model which can be implemented in many different ways, including a pure C or C++ low-level implementation. On the other hand, Erlang processes are lightweight preemptive language features that allow to run a vast amount of processes in parallel much more effectively than it would be possible using native system processes or even threads. It happens that they are modelled after the mathematical model, but it was a design decision based on [specific requirements](http://ftp.nsysu.edu.tw/FreeBSD/ports/distfiles/erlang/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf).

I think it would all fit better together if you discussed briefly the Actor model as a mathematical model on its own and only then how it has been implemented in Erlang, pointing out any differences and features specific to Erlang.

Comment: You included the whole of Joe Armstrong's thesis as a reference. I guess Ch.2.4 and 3.4 are relevant for the question at hand. In your opinion, is there anything else I should pay particular attention to? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, 2.4 and 3.4 are a good start, but also: 2.2, 2.3, 2.5 and 3.10 which lay out requirements for Erlang applications; 2.10 and 3-3.1 which explains why Erlang is a Message-oriented language; 3.5.6 and 3.6 describing links and monitors, which are essential parts of Erlang processes not quite required by the Actor model; 3.7 which allows to represent external processes with internal Erlang processes; 4 and 6 discuss OTP behaviours, which can be compared to behaviors in the Actor model. It's also worth noting that messages in Erlang are ordered (2.4.5), whereas in the Actor model they are not.

Comment: I've read through most of Armstrong's thesis and there is no mention of actors whatsoever. Moreover, it is clear from both the thesis and many other sources (I guess Armstrong's book Programming Erlang or the tutorial [Learn You Some Erlang for Great Good](http://learnyousomeerlang.com) are good places to start), that Erlang to a great extent puts into practice the philosophy of the actor model, but the Erlang processes are - as you say - a practical implementation that is something different from the model. I guess I'll stick to explaining processes :)

Comment: I wanted to mention that Actor model is not mentioned in the thesis at all but the comment field was too short :) In OOP languages the OO principles were a design decision when writing them, e.g. Ruby or C++. It's not like that with Erlang. The primary objectives for Erlang were concurrency, soft real-time, distribution, continuous operation, fault tolerance, etc. Being an Actor Oriented wasn't. It just happens that Actor model is good at modelling some of those characteristics, e.g. concurrency, so Erlang involuntarily implements some of those principles, but Erlang is much more than that :)